# How to return a FILE* fp from a function to my main in c

Tags: c, file-handling

Hello I practice with file handling in C and I try to make a code about removing comments.
I make it with main.c, functions.c and functions.h **.**

main.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.c"

int main(void) {

    FILE *in ,*out;
    char c;

    if ((in = fopen("input_file.c", "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error opening \"file1.txt\" for reading\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((out = fopen("input_file.nocmments.c","w")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error opening \"file2.txt\" for writing\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    while((c = getc(in)) != EOF) {
        if(c == '/') comment(c, in, out);
        else if (c == '\'' || c == '\"') quotes(c, in, out);
        else print(c, out);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

function.c (I will show only a part because there is the same problem to other functions too

```
int one_line(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout) {
    while ((ch = getc(fpin)) != '\n');
    fputc(ch, fpout);
    return ch, fpin, fpout; <-- error here
}
```

function.h

```
int comment(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout);
int one_line(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout);
int multiline(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout);
int quotes(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout);
int print(char ch, FILE* fpout);
```

So when I compile the code I get the following warning

```
returning ‘FILE *’ {aka ‘struct _IO_FILE *’} from a function with return type ‘int’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

I understand that I can't return **typedef** and that's why I get the following problem, but how can I return the file pointer to my main function?
(Sorry if my question is stupid)

Comment: You can only return _one_ thing from a C function.  It looks like `fpin` and `fpout` are inputs. Why are you trying to return them?

Comment: In fact, it looks like your functions don’t need to return anything at all.

Comment: @Max I wouldn't be surprised if OP has tried to create a minimal reproducible example and the described functionality is needed for other functions with the same problem

Comment: @Max That was actually the key question thank you

Comment: When you say "*I understand that I can't return **typedef***", I suspect that you mean that you think you cannot return a *structure*. `typedef` is a keyword, not a type category, and although some make a habit of using it to define aliases for structure types, it is never actually required for any purpose.  In any case, yes, you *can* return a structure.  The only types you cannot return are functions and arrays, though you can return pointers to these.

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include "functions.c"`  DO NOT include *.c files.  Rather write a header file that contains the external interface of the function, then include that header file in the *.c file and in any other *.c files that use the functionality of the `functions.c` file

Comment: OT:  the file `function.h`  should include a 'include guard' similar to: `#ifndef FUNCTION_H   newline  #define FUNCTION_H newline  <contents of header file>  newline #endif

Comment: OT: regarding: `int one_line(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout) {
    while ((ch = getc(fpin)) != '\n');`  This overwrites the value passed in by the function parameter.  (but does not change the value in the calling function)

Comment: regarding: `char c;` and `while((c = getc(in)) != EOF) {`  The function `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.  And depending on your implementation of `char` might be unable to recognize `EOF`

Comment: regarding: `int one_line(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout) {`  This function is trying to return a `char` and a `pointer` and a `pointer` but the prototype for this function states that a `int` will be returned.

Comment: regarding: `while ((ch = getc(fpin)) != '\n');` This will execute a loop that continues until a newline is encountered.    Is that what you want?

Comment: regarding: `if ((in = fopen("input_file.c", "r")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error opening \"file1.txt\" for reading\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((out = fopen("input_file.nocmments.c","w")) == NULL ) {
        printf("Error opening \"file2.txt\" for writing\n");`  1) should be using `perror()` rather than `printf()` so the reason the system thinks the call failed will be passed to `stderr`  2)`file2.txt` is NOT `input_file.nocmments.c`  3) `file1.txt` is not `input_file.c`

Comment: regarding: `if(c == '/') comment(c, in, out);` if the *.c file contains a division operation this will misidentify that division as a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```c
int one_line(char ch, FILE* fpin, FILE* fpout) {
    while ((ch = getc(fpin)) != '\n');
    fputc(ch, fpout);
    return ch, fpin, fpout; <-- error here
}
```

C has a few tricky or confusing details. The comma operator is one of them.

```c
    return ch, fpin, fpout;
```

This is valid C code. The comma operator is defined in C11 section 6.5.17, which says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression;
> there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right
> operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

In your example, this means:

- First, the expression `ch` is evaluated, and since it doesn't have any side effects, it is ignored.
- Second, `fpin` is evaluated and ignored as well.
- Third, `fpout` is evaluated and returned from the function.

The type of `fpout` is `FILE *`, the return type of the function is `int`, these types don't match, and this is where the compiler warning comes from.

You should change your code to simply `return ch`.

You do not need to return the files from the function, even though you modified them. The point here is that you didn't pass the actual files to the function, but *pointers* to the files.